# How can I fix a SDL2 Compile Error using gcc?

Tags: c, sdl-2

When I compile my code using gcc, the link problem keep showing.

```
"/usr/local/include/sdl2_ttf/2.0.15/include/SDL2/SDL_ttf.h:34:10: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
   34 | #include "SDL.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated."
```

I have used the compile command:

```
gcc main.c -I /usr/local/include/sdl2/2.0.10/include -L /usr/local/include/sdl2/2.0.10/lib -I /usr/local/include/sdl2_ttf/2.0.15/include -L /usr/local/include/sdl2_ttf/2.0.15/lib -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf
```

and actually the `<SDL2/SDL.h>` has been linked successfully. However, I think the problems occurred because there is no `SDL.h` file in `SDl2_ttf/include` file. How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `#include "SDL/SDL.h"`

Comment: That's a compilation error, not a linking error.

Comment: Have you actually installed the SDL2 library on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Use the include directive

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

and compile your program with

```
gcc main.c $(sdl-config --cflags) $(sdl-config --libs)
```

Comment: I am sorry. This doesn't work. It shows that main.c:2:10: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Comment: @BruceWayne It should be `#include <SDL.h>`.